# Download HTML5 Video to IOS Camera Roll From Web

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, html5-video

I have a website that makes it easy for users to upload videos and then share them with their email/CRM list. Essentially I create a website/landing page for each video, and the emails link to the website/landing page where users can watch the video. I would love to add a "download" button so people watching or visiting the landing page on their mobile device could save the video to their camera roll for later viewing.

I have tried just a normal Download but it doesn't download on mobile.

```
 <video src={videoURL} />
 <a href={videoURL} download>Download</a>
```

I expect the  Download to take the user to a new page where the user's could save the video to their camera roll, but no luck. How can I add a download button that will allow the user's to save the video to their IOS camera roll?

Comment: Any luck Will? I'm in the same boat